# Entry level python code passing str to int error

Tags: python, string, integer

I'm running into some problems trying to calculate a number based on user input.

the input for height is the issue first issue. The user puts in 5.9 feet, it of course is input as a string.

Attempting to convert to INT which I assumed would round to 6 then its height times itself divided by weight.

However, how I know how to convert a string into an INT doesn't seem to apply here

````
``` 
print("Today we are going to calculate your BMI")
weight = input("What is your weight? ")
height = input("What is your height? ")
    
#weight = 175
#height = 5.9  
    
weight_int = int(weight)
height_int = int(height*height)
    
print("Congratulations your BMI is " + weight_int / height_int)
```
When I run this, I get the following error:
```
````

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'**

Comment: You're multiplying your height variable by itself before casting it to an int, which is probably your issue. You should also include your error as part of the question to help others help you!

Comment: Convert `height` to `int` same as you did for `weight`  --> `height = int(height); height_int = int(height*height)`

Comment: As @PirateNinjas + Why are you casting the inputs to `int` when it looks like (from yours comments) that you would accept `float` ?

Comment: The problem required whole numbers as a output

Answer (score 1):

You look to be multiplying your height by itself before casting to int. Instead do it later, like:

```
print("Today we are going to calculate your BMI")
weight = input("What is your weight? ")
height = input("What is your height? ")

weight_float = float(weight)
height_float = float(height)

print("Congratulations your BMI is " + str(weight_float / (height_float * height_float)))
```

Note the key changes:

1. height is cast from string to float before trying to multiply it. Float is probably better for your use case than int.
2. we calculate the bmi in the print statement in full
3. we need to cast the bmi back to a string to concatenate with the string

You could also use an f-string for the last part:

```
print(f"Congratulations your BMI is {weight_float / (height_float * height_float)}")
```